# get content inside ng-template angular

Tags: angular, typescript

We are using Signature Pad

npm i signature_pad

```
<ng-template #signatureTemplate>
<canvas #canvas width="400" height="300"></canvas>
</ng-template>

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild("canvas", { static: true }) canvas: ElementRef;
  sig: SignaturePad;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sig = new SignaturePad(this.canvas.nativeElement);
  }
}
```

this.canvas.nativeElement is always null.

But when canvas is removed from ng-teamplate it works as intented. How to get canvas inside ng-template ?

Comment: You cannot. Why do you need the template in the first place ?

Comment: Seems like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Tell us what you are trying to do instead !

Comment: Why ngOnInit() ? You will have access once template is rendered, so use ngAfterViewInit() instead.